# Trouble deciphering java class not visible from class loader error

Tags: java, ikpicturetaker, rococoa

I am trying to write some java code that will code the will get the Cocoa IKPictureTaker widget to load using Rococoa.  I feel like I am getting closer now but I am getting an error and I am not quite sure why it is occurring.  The error that I am getting is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at IKPictureTakerTest.main(IKPictureTakerTest.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface IKPictureTaker$_Class is not visible from class loader
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:353)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:581)
at org.rococoa.Rococoa.createProxy(Rococoa.java:164)
at org.rococoa.Rococoa.wrap(Rococoa.java:118)
at org.rococoa.Rococoa.createClass(Rococoa.java:50)
at IKPictureTaker.<clinit>(IKPictureTaker.java:31)
```

So there are two small classes that are interacting here first is the IKPictureTaker class:

```
public interface IKPictureTaker extends NSObject
{
   public static final _Class MYCLASS = Rococoa.createClass("IKPictureTaker", _Class.class);

   public interface _Class extends NSClass
   {
   /**
   * Returns a shared {@code IKPictureTaker} instance, creating it if necessary.
   * @return an {@code IKPictureTaker} object.
   */
   IKPictureTaker pictureTaker();
   }

   NSInteger runModal();
}
```

And the test class:

```
public class IKPictureTakerTest extends JFrame
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      // You need a GUI before this will work.
      new IKPictureTakerTest().setVisible(true);

      NSAutoreleasePool pool = NSAutoreleasePool.new_();

      QTKit instance = QTKit.instance;
      // Initialize the Quartz framework.
      Quartz.instance.toString();

      // Display the dialog.
     IKPictureTaker pictureTaker = IKPictureTaker.MYCLASS.pictureTaker();
     NSInteger result = pictureTaker.runModal();

     if (result.intValue() == 0) // NSCancelButton
     {
        System.out.println("User cancelled.");
     }
     else
     {
        assert result.intValue() == 1; // NSOKButton
        System.out.println("User chose an image.");
     }

     pool.release();
   }
}
```

This is the first time that I have done any command line compilation in java so I think that maybe by linker error is coming from that but I am not sure.  Could anyone give me a hint as to what might be going on here?

P.S. It might be important to note that the Cocoa application does pop up with an empty window before this error occurs but there is not contents.

Comment: Are you sure you compiled all the files before trying to run the code?

Comment: yes I did a javac *.java and all the files are in the same directory.

Comment: The directory contains: IKPictureTaker$_Class.class QTKit.class
IKPictureTaker.class  QTKit.java
IKPictureTaker.java  Quartz.class
IKPictureTakerTest.class Quartz.java
IKPictureTakerTest.java
QTKit and Quartz are small one line classes.  I think the class in question in the error is the nested interface: public interface _Class extends NSClass

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your one line classes have (that is what libs are being loaded), but I think that's where your problem is. I got it to work by making sure Quartz is being loaded:

```
public interface IKPictureTaker extends NSObject {

    Library quartzINSTANCE = (Library) Native.loadLibrary("Quartz", Library.class);
    //...

}

public class IKPictureTakerTest extends JFrame {

   //...

   //QTKit instance = QTKit.instance;

   //Quartz.instance.toString();

   //...

}
```

Comment: weird I added those changes and get this same problem, how are you compiling it?  I am doing javac *.java then java -Djna.library.path=/Library/Java/Extensions/bin IKPictureTakerTest
 to run it.  Is that maybe the difference?  Can you by chance send me your version that works to mike_minerva@yahoo.com?